# NullPointerException when running Grails 3.0.3

Tags: java, grails, sdkman

I installed Grails 3.0.3 via [sdkman](http://sdkman.io/) on my laptop running Yosemite.

```
lightning-strike-2:server2 benstpierre$ grails
Usage:
     create-app [NAME] --profile=web
     create-plugin [NAME] --profile=web-plugin


| Error Error occurred running Grails CLI: null (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
lightning-strike-2:server2 benstpierre$
```

When I run the same command with --stacktrace I get the following...

```
lightning-strike-2:server2 benstpierre$ grails --stacktrace
Usage:
     create-app [NAME] --profile=web
     create-plugin [NAME] --profile=web-plugin


| Error Error occurred running Grails CLI: null (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.grails.cli.profile.git.GitProfileRepository.getAllProfiles(GitProfileRepository.groovy:72)
    at org.grails.cli.profile.commands.ListProfilesCommand.handle(ListProfilesCommand.groovy:43)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.execute(GrailsCli.groovy:177)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.getBaseUsage(GrailsCli.groovy:122)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.execute(GrailsCli.groovy:166)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.main(GrailsCli.groovy:99)
| Error Error occurred running Grails CLI: null
```

I have no idea how to fix this any ideas?

Comment: [`GitProfileRepository`](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-shell/src/main/groovy/org/grails/cli/profile/git/GitProfileRepository.groovy#L39) (The class which throws NPE) has been deprecated with latest versions. You can upgrade Grails to latest stable v3.0.9 and not see this issue. On a side note, make sure you have [`profiles`](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/3.0.x/grails-shell/src/main/groovy/org/grails/cli/profile/git/GitProfileRepository.groovy#L72) directory present under `~/.grails/profiles/`